# Postgres normalize human name string

Tags: postgresql, normalization

Is there some function to normalize name string:

```
 select normalize('R.C. Bray') 

 'R. C. Bray'
```

Or the opposite direction?

The simple `replace('. ', '.')` or `replace('.', '. ')` is wrong and may be effect another data.

Answer (score 1):

`regexp_replace` should be enough:

```
regexp_replace('R.C. Bray.', '([A-Z])(\.)(\w)', '\1\2 \3', 'g')
```

This replaces a single upper case letter followed by a `.` directly followed by a "word character" by inserting a space between the dot and the character. It leaves dots that have a whitespace after them untouched.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  regexp_replace(array_to_string(string_to_array('R.C. Bray', '.'), '. '), '[ ]+', ' ', 'g');
```

Can be work. But may be not a good method.